# Remove non printable characters C# multilanguage

Tags: c#

I have a multi-language application in asp.net C#. Here I have to  create a zip file and use some items from the database to construct file name. I strip out special characters from file name. However if the language is German for example my trimming algorithm will remove some german characters like Umlaut.

Could someone provide me with a language adaptable trimming algorithm.

Here is my code:

```
private string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
{
    return str;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') | c == '.' || c == '_' || c == ' ' || c == '+')
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

thanks

Comment: private string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
        {
            return str;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') | c == '.' || c == '_' || c == ' ' || c == '+')
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

Comment: That should be in the question. I added it for you. And I don't understand why you immediately return the original string.

Comment: @josephj1989 You can use `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` to get a list of characters that can't appear in a file name.  You can use that list to decide which characters to remove from the zip filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean the name of the ZIP file, instead of the names inside the ZIP file, you probably want to check if the character is valid for a filename, which will allow you to use more than just letters or digits:

```
char[] invalid = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();

string s = "abcöü*/";
var newstr = new String(s.Where(c => !invalid.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: This should also allow the OP to use umlauts since they're perfectly valid in filenames, except the question states that's what they want to remove. (That said I agree it's still a good idea to check against that array in addition to the stripping.)

Comment: @millimoose I couldn't tell if he wanted to strip out umlauts, etc., or if he was complaining that his version unnecessarily stripped them out (OPs phrase "language adaptable").

Answer (score 5):

```
string s = "abcöü*/";
var newstr = new String( s.Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray() );
```

Comment: Looks sweet. I guess you should also handle the case if all letters get stripped out.

Comment: @Holf I'll leave that part to OP

Comment: Did you mean: `Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))`

Comment: @KendallFrey Why would you create a function that has the exact same parameters, return type, and return value as a standard library function, and in it, do nothing more than call that standard library function?

Comment: @hvd: Nice one! I see it now. Clever.

Answer (score 4):

A more versatile variant that will mangle the string less is:

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string s)
{
    // split accented characters into surrogate pairs
    IEnumerable<char> chars = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    // remove all non-ASCII characters – i.e. the accents
    return new string(chars.Where(c => c < 0x7f && !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
}
```

This should remove most problematic characters while still preserving most of the text. (If you're creating filenames, you might also want to replace newlines and tabs with the space character.)

Comment: More precisely, it decomposes precomposed characters, so when you strip the non-ASCII characters, you are left with the base character.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Exactly. It will likely break when the base letter is non-ASCII as well but that shouldn't be the case (often) for Western European languages. (E.g. it won't replace the Turkish dotless i with a regular one.)

Answer (score 1):

One-liner, assuming ASCII where non-printable are essentially all chars before the space:

```
var safeString = new string(str.Select(c=>c<' '?'_':c).ToArray());
```